# How does sum of squared difference algorithm work?

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing

I have a two images a and b, where b is a block of image a. I want to find b using block matching. How do I go about it?

Comment: Are you asking how the algorithm works? Or are you asking how to implement it? Your title implies the former, but the body of your question implies the latter. If you want implementation details, you need to say what platform/OS and environment you are using as well.

Comment: what: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_absolute_differences
how: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#matchtemplate

Comment: I actually want to implement it. I have two images a and b, where b is translated image of a and now I have to apply SSD. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 19):

It's very simple, in fact the name tells you pretty much everything you need to know - you just calculate the sum of the squared difference value for each pixel.

To calculate the SSD for two images:

```
ssd = 0
for i = 0 to height - 1
    for j = 0 to width - 1
        diff = A[i][j] - B[i][j]
        ssd += diff * diff
```

The general idea is that for matching images the SSD will be small. If you're trying to match two images, where one image is translated by some amount, then you would typically do a brute force approach where you calculate the SSD over a range of x, y displacements and then identify the minimum SSD value, which should then correspond to the best alignment offset.

Note that SSD is generally only used due to its simplicity and relatively low computational cost - in general you will get better results using [Normalized Cross Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalization).

Comment: Thank you! But If I am having images of two different sizes? say the second image is a sub-image of first one, then how do I apply SSD to find the matching block Is there anyother simple block-matching algorithm ?

Comment: You just apply SSD between the sub-image and to a block within the main image with the same dimensions. You move this block around within the main image and repeatedly calculate the SSD if you are looking to find a match using the minimum SSD value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find a position of a block b inside an image a, you can save a lot of computing power by building a [Gaussian pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing)) of both images and start looking at the smallest going up as you find.

The smallest image would give you quick calculations but an estimate result - this estimate result can be later used in the next level of the pyramid to narrow your search area and get a better precision result.
You continue like that until you reach level 0 of your pyramid which is you original image.