# Calculating a single representative "pixel value" from a RGB value

Tags: image, image-processing, colors, rgb

My question is related to this stack overflow discussion here.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161780/about-sum-of-squared-differences

The discussion gives us the formula for the sum of squared differences and an answer gives the following example.

---

For example, if you are comparing two pixels (i.e. one pixel in each image), you have a region of 1 pixel. Let's say it is the fifth pixel in the first row: x = 0, y = 4. The pixel values are 10,3 for f,g respectively. For the region of one 2n1=1=>n1=0, and the same goes for n2.

SSD=(f(x+i,y+j)−g(x+i,y+j))<sup>2</sup>
SSD=(f(0+0,4+0)−g(0+0,4+0))<sup>2</sup>

SSD=(f(0,4)−g(0,4))2
SSD=(10−3)2=49

---

My question is how is he getting the pixel values of 10 for f(x,y) and 3 for g(x,y) from the RGB values for each pixel? RGB are not a single value. That is when I have a single pixel of an image I have a triplet of information: I have the red, green, and blue color values. How does one go from this RGB value to a single value as the example provides?

Comment: If you are asking about the programming language called `Processing`, then there are a wealth of built-in functions for manipulating colors. If you are *not* asking about that particular programming language, please delete that tag since it is not an alias for `image-processing` (which seems to be your concern here).

Comment: I untagged this as a Processing question. If it is a Processing question, then please post a [mcve] demonstrating what you have so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume he's using a grayscale color representation, where the values 10 and 3 correspond the to brightness, or luminosity, of the two pixels.

There *is* a method to convert RGB to an integer representation:

```
RGB (int) = 

R * (256^2) + 

G * (256) + 

B
```

... *However*, calculating SSD between values in this representation will be meaningless, which brings us to the question of calculating colour distance in general: any attempt to flatten RGB into a single dimension will inevitably collapse some of the information.

Representing your RGB values as HSL/HSB/HSV may enable you to compare hues, or saturation, or brightness more meaningfully (one dimension at a time), but it is hard to collapse and compare all 3 dimensions at once in a meaningful manner.

You may find [this](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/09/30/colour-sorting/) article of use.

Answer (score 1):

**(1)**

> *"...How is he getting the pixel values of 10 for f(x,y) and 3 for g(x,y) from the RGB values for each pixel?"*

These seem like just basic example values to make it easier to illustrate his point. You could still use the full RGB value in calculations (*eg:* `16777215` for all-white pixel).

See also this answer: [How does sum of squared difference algorithm work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26011339/2057709)

**(2)**
If instead you prefer `255` as flat value for a white pixel see below:

> *"RGB are not a single value... I have a triplet of information: I have the red, green, and blue color values. How does one go from this RGB value to a single value as the example provides?"*

Take your `input_rgb` value and break it up to R-G-B components..

```
temp_R = input_rgb >> 16 & 0x0ff; in
temp_G = input_rgb >> 8 & 0x0ff;
temp_B = input_rgb >> 0 & 0x0ff;
```

Then to get a single representative value (pixel's luminance)

```
value = (temp_R + temp_G + temp_B) / 3 ); //# averaged, gives range between 0 and 255
```

You can further reduce the result `value` into range of between 0 and 1 by doing a `(value / 255)`